# Failed to build Kotlin code with proto models using Bazel

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm trying to use compiled proto models into my kotlin code. Project is managed by bazel. So I reproduce problem with simple "HelloWorld" project.

WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_KOTLIN_VERSION = "9051eb053f9c958440603d557316a6e9fda14687"

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_kotlin",
    sha256 = "c36e71eec84c0e17dd098143a9d93d5720e81b4db32bceaf2daf939252352727",
    strip_prefix = "rules_kotlin-%s" % RULES_KOTLIN_VERSION,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/archive/%s.tar.gz" % RULES_KOTLIN_VERSION,
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kotlin_repositories", "kt_register_toolchains")

kotlin_repositories()
kt_register_toolchains()


http_archive(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    strip_prefix = "protobuf-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/master.zip"],
)

load("@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_deps.bzl", "protobuf_deps")

protobuf_deps()
```

BUILD

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")

load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_binary", "java_lite_proto_library", "java_proto_library")
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

proto_library(
    name = "clicklocation_proto",
    srcs = ["ClickLocation.proto"],
)

java_proto_library(
    name = "clicklocation_java_lite_proto",
    deps = [":clicklocation_proto"],
)

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "app_lib",
    srcs = ["Main.kt"],
    deps = [":clicklocation_java_lite_proto"]
)

java_binary(
    name = "myapp",
    main_class = "MyApp",
    runtime_deps = [":app_lib"],
)
```

Proto file

```
syntax = "proto2";

package objectrecognition;
option java_package = "com.kshmax.objectrecognition.proto";
option java_outer_classname = "ClickLocationProtos";
message ClickLocation {
    required float x = 1;
    required float y = 2;
}
```

Main.kt

```
import com.kshmax.objectrecognition.proto.ClickLocationProtos

class MyApp {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val location = ClickLocationProtos.ClickLocation.newBuilder()
        location.x = 0.1f
        location.y = 0.2f
        location.build()
    }
  }
}
```

I have done it as described in protocolbuffers/protobuf repository examples .
But I got an error:

> error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please
>   make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class
>   com.kshmax.objectrecognition.proto.ClickLocationProtos.ClickLocation,
>   unresolved supertypes: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 class
>   com.kshmax.objectrecognition.proto.ClickLocationProtos.ClickLocationOrBuilder,
>   unresolved supertypes: com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder class
>   com.kshmax.objectrecognition.proto.ClickLocationProtos.ClickLocation.Builder,
>   unresolved supertypes: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.Builder

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code that uses protobuf needs to depend on the protobuf library itself.

In theory, this could be exported by the rule, but since it doesn't work, I would add a dep on protobuf directly, similarly to [BuildEventServiceTest](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/a4de484efe44c3e614ba7901a5e03e3958c148e9/src/test/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventservice/BUILD#L39)

```
deps= [
  "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_java",
  "my_foo_java_proto",
]
```

or `java_lite_proto_library` / `"@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_java_lite"` where the remote repository was [defined in the WORKSPACE](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/ee12c173b8911fbb71d1486cb421ee83b6bf6b22/WORKSPACE#L96) as

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    patch_args = ["-p1"],
    patches = ["@io_bazel//third_party/protobuf:3.11.3.patch"],
    patch_cmds = EXPORT_WORKSPACE_IN_BUILD_FILE,
    patch_cmds_win = EXPORT_WORKSPACE_IN_BUILD_FILE_WIN,
    sha256 = "cf754718b0aa945b00550ed7962ddc167167bd922b842199eeb6505e6f344852",
    strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.11.3",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.11.3.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.11.3.tar.gz",
    ],
)
```

(I'm not sure you need the patch, and there might be a more recent version; [look at the example](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/examples/WORKSPACE))